# How do you check if date is in correct format

Tags: c

For example in input.txt file there is date `20210405`. Date is in `rrrrmmdd` format without any `'/'` or `'.'`. How do you check if date is in correct format not in `20211405`?.
My code works only for numbers that dont have zero in day for example `05`,`07`,`08`, my code works only for `10` or `11`. How do I fix that?

```
int main() {
  char load[50];
  long year, day, month;
  int lenght, lenght2, lenght3;
  int i = 0;
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen("input.txt", "r");

  while (fgets(load, sizeof load, file) != NULL) {
    if (i == 0) {
      if (strlen(load) == 8) {
        year = strtol(load, NULL, 10);
        month = year;
        day = year;
        year = year * 0.0001;
        lenght = (log10(abs(year))) + 1;

        if (lenght == 4) {
          day = day % 100;
          lenght2 = (log10(abs(day))) + 1;

          if (lenght2 == 2 && day <=31) {
            month = (month % 10000) - 30;
            month = month / 100;
            lenght3 = (log10(abs(day))) + 1;

            if (month <= 12 && lenght2 == 2) {
              printf("Datum: %s", load);
            } else {
              printf("Invalid input.");
            }
          } else {
            printf("Invalid input.");
          }
        } else {
          printf("Invalid input.");
        }
      } else {
            printf("Invalid input.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a perfect example program for learning how to use a debugger.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should apply some proper formatting to your code. Don't use lengthy lines that contain tons of statements. Use a statement per line. Otherwise it is way too easy to miss some isntruction. Also apply proper indentation. Currently that's quite a mess.

Comment: @Gerhardh ya i know, but im fresh beginner, im trying my best, i hate to use if

Comment: You are dealing with integers. Don't use floating point calculations on them. That introduces rounding errors. Also don't use `log10` to get the "length".

Comment: As a fresh beginner it is even more important to apply proper formatting. It makes the code better readable. Experienced programmers can read it also when formatted in a mess. Do yourself a favor by reformatting.

Comment: Before you can write code to determine if a date is valid, you must have a detailed and rigorously defined description of what a valid date format is. This ranges from "human readable with internationalization" (where you can expect a literal world of complications), to "machine readable" (where you could use something much more efficient like "days since epoch in hexadecimal").

Answer (score 1):

You have a few flaws in your code:

1. `fgets` includes a `\n` at the end of your string if it is found in the file. Unless you read the last line where no more `\n` is present, you will get 9 characters in your buffer.
   Your condition `if (strlen(load) == 8)` will fail in the other cases.
2. You should not use floating point operations on integers.
   `year = year * 0.0001;` In best case it is identical to `year = year / 10000;`, in worst case you get some rounding errors.
3. You check the "length" of the value for `day` and `month` by taking `log10`. That means that the numerical value must be >10 to get a length of 2. That is exactly what you are complaining about. 
   A proper check for valid valued would be to check whether the numerical value is in proper range.
4. For some reason to reduce `month` by 30. That doesn't really make much sense.
5. You don't use variable `i` at all. The corresponding `if (i==0)` is rather useless.

A fixed version could look like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  char load[50];
  long year, day, month;
  bool valid = false;

  FILE* file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
  // TODO: Check for NULL

  while (fgets(load, sizeof load, file) != NULL) {

    // Remove trailing '\n' 
    int len = strlen(load);
    if (load[len-1] == '\n') {
      load[len-1] = 0;
    }

    // Do we have exactly 8 digits?
    if (strlen(load) == 8) {

      long value =  strtol(load, NULL, 10);
      year = value / 10000;
      month = (value / 100) % 100;
      day = value % 100;

      if (year >= 1000) {
          if (day > 0 && day <= 31) {
            if (month > 0 && month <= 12) {
              valid = true;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      if (valid) {
        printf("Datum: %s", load);
      }
      else {
        printf("Invalid input.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: really helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to use floating point arithmetics to split the value into the year, month and day parts. The main reason for this is floating point numbers are represented internally in base 2 so `0.0001` is not represented exactly, so converting the multiplication result to `long` may cause truncation of the value.

You should instead use integer arithmetics this way:

```
  long value = strtol(load, NULL, 10);
  year = value / 10000;
  month = (value / 100) % 100;
  day = value % 100;
```

You could also use `sscanf()` to parse the line directly into 3 `int` values:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char load[50];
    int year, day, month;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *file = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open input.txt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(load, sizeof load, file) != NULL) {
        if (i++ == 0) {
            static const int mlen[] = { 0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
            char c[2];

            /* accept up to 4 bytes for year, 2 for month, 2 for day and check for a trailing newline */
            if (sscanf(load, "%4d%2d%2d%1[\n]", &year, &month, &day, c) != 4) {
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid date line: %s", load);
                break;
            }
            if (year < 1901 || year > 2099
            ||  month < 1 || month > 12
            ||  day < 1 || day > mlen[month]
            ||  (day == 29 && month == 2 && year % 4 != 0)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid date: %d/%d/%d\n", day, month, year);
                break;
            }
            printf("Datum: %s", load);
        } else {
            /* handle other lines */
            ...
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```